# Cannot usу btree_gist with distance operator on Windows

Tags: postgresql, btree-gist

Why I can't force to work these queries:

```
select '2018-09-10 03:00:00+03'::timestamptz <-> '2018-09-10 03:00:00+03'::timestamptz

select * from T
order by time <-> '2018-09-10 03:00:00+03'::timestamptz
limit 1
```

> Error: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone <-> timestamp with time zone

I also tried to install pg_trgm.

PostgreSQL 12.2

btree_gist 1.5

Windows Server 2012 R2

**What I did wrong?**

Comment: If you want the "distance" between two timestamps, just subtract them: `'2018-09-10 03:00:00+03'::timestamptz - '2018-09-10 03:00:00+03'::timestamptz`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the main case for me is using btree_gist index in sorting and using distance operator.

Comment: Are you sure "create extension btree_gist" succeeded? Was it created in a schema in your search_path?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I've checked several times.